# logdata to InfluxDB

Tags: logs

I have this script that takes download speed and puts data into a logfile.

```
$ wget -O /dev/null ftp://someftpsite:password@ftp.test.com/testdump300 2>&1 | \
   awk '/[0-9]+ [M]B\/s/{ sub("\\(",""); print $1,$2,$3 }' >> wget300.log
```

In the same "line" I really want to put it into InfluxDB, so I can show the data in Grafana.

Is that possible and how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the same "line" I really want to put it into InfluxDB, so I can show the data in Grafana.

This is possible, the easiest method would be to use the influxDB CLI tool to import this data into your database from a file that you've got it written to. `datarrr.txt` would be that file.

```
$ influx -import -path=datarrr.txt -precision=s
```

Where your DDL file (`datarrr.txt`) would look like this:

```
# DDL
CREATE DATABASE pirates
CREATE RETENTION POLICY oneday ON pirates DURATION 1d REPLICATION 1

# DML
# CONTEXT-DATABASE: pirates
# CONTEXT-RETENTION-POLICY: oneday

treasures,captain_id=dread_pirate_roberts value=801 1439856000
treasures,captain_id=flint value=29 1439856000
treasures,captain_id=sparrow value=38 1439856000
treasures,captain_id=tetra value=47 1439856000
treasures,captain_id=crunch value=109 1439858880
```

You'd need to change things around to match whatever DDL (schema) you're planning to use for your influxDB DB.

#### References

- [An Introduction to InfluxDB, a Time Series Database](https://opensourceforu.com/2016/12/introduction-influxdb-time-series-database/)
- [InfluxDB command line interface (CLI/shell)](http://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/tools/shell/)